# How to show an array's contents?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have a function (this function is from a class) from [Github](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/master/index.php)

```
<?php
   function func ($expr, $bindParams = null) {
      return Array ("[F]" => Array($expr, $bindParams));
   }
   $a = func('SHA1(?)', array("MYPASSWORD".'salt123'));
   echo $a;
?>
```

This `$a` shows as `array`. I think the above function is for encrypting password. How can I echo this encrypted `$a`?

Comment: it returns `array(1) { ["[F]"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "SHA1(?)" [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(17) "MYPASSWORDsalt123" } } }`. Is this function encrypts my password?

Comment: No, it will just put your data into an array

Answer (score 0):

To see the contents of array you can use.

1. `print_r($a));` or if you want nicely formatted array then

   echo '

   ```
   '; print_r($a)); echo '
   ```

   ';
2. use `var_dump($a))` to get more information of the content in the array like datatype and length.
3. you can loop the array using php's foreach(); and get the desired output. more info on foreach in php's documentation website https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

Array's cannot be echoed. PHP has a perfect debug function to do this called `var_dump()`.

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($a);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

It can also be done using the `print_r()` function.

**Note on `var_dump()`**: It will not dump the complete array most of the times. You can set the depth for `var_dump()` in your php.ini file.